# Assigning value to constant empty dictionary for first time in swift language

Tags: swift

If I declare an empty Constant dictionary and want to initialize later, How can I do it?

```
let emptyDictionary = Dictionary<String, Float>()
```

How can i assign value to `emptyDictionary`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.
You have to create a **variable Dictionary**:

```
var emptyDictionary = Dictionary<String, Float>()
emptyDictionary["key"] = 3.0
```

Or create a filled constant Dictionary:

```
let emptyDictionary = ["Key": 3.0]
```